# How do I force a rebuild on OpenShift?

Tags: node.js, web-hosting

I want to force a clean rebuild of my OpenShift application. The issue is npm is having problems so it can't run gunt successfully.

I don't want to delete the whole application because my Domain is already pointing at it. I just making random commit isn't fixing the issue.

How can I make OpenShift do a clean checkout of the repo and rebuild everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is an explicit [deploy](https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/deployments.html#using-the-deploy-command) command:

```
rhc deploy <branch name> -a <app name>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to force a rebuild on OpenShift is by using marker files. Simply by creating an empty file

```
.openshift/markers/force_clean_build
```

will tell OpenShift to rebuild the whole gear. You can find more information on OpenShift site:

https://developers.openshift.com/languages/nodejs/markers.html